# Spree commerce Google analytics update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, spree

I need to update Spree Commerce web-shop's Google Analytics code to be able to track demographics.

```
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948
```

I have the full source code of website downloaded.

When I do a text search over the whole code I am unable to find anything Google related, or even a string `"ga.js"`. Obviously I am missing something, but how do I go about even to start figuring this out?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Search over a local clone of spree. https://github.com/spree/spree.git

Grep for `ga.js`

You will find this file: `core/app/views/spree/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb`

**Copy** it to your own code base at: `app/views/spree/shared/_google_analytics.html.erb`

Change what you need to change.

Comment: This is the correct answer. 

If it's a change that would be relevant to all Spree stores (sending additional information to Google Analytics that's readily available in the store with no customization), please consider submitting a pull request to add it to core!

Comment: According to the analytics support page the change is necessary for supporting google Remarketing and GDN Impression Reporting. Not all Spree stores necessarily use these google analytics services. Creating a constant in config called Spree::GDN which can be used to choose which ga.src to use might be a better way to go.